# How to pass a 1D array of 500 pointers to a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, c-strings

The programm is compiling ok but once the user inputs something to the array it crashes. Any help will be appreciated :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void Register(char *arr[],char arr2[]);
int main() {
    char *Username[500];
    char table1[20];
    Register(Username,table1);
    return 0;
}   
void Register(char *Username[],char table1[]){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 500; i++){
        scanf("%s",&table1);
        Username[i] = table1;
        printf("for i = %d username[%d] is %s\n\n",i,i,Username[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a 1d array of 500 pointers. Each of them will point to the same 1d array of 20 characters `Username[i] = table1`.

Comment: yup that i am new to c so i dont really knew how to explain it :)

Comment: regarding: `for(i = 0; i < 500; x1++){`  The third parameter is not correct.  The staement should be: `for( i = 0; i < 500; i++ ){`

Comment: OT: regarding the function name: `Register()`  The C language has the type modifier: `register`.  It is a poor programming practice to use names those only difference between a name in the C language is the capitalization

Comment: OT: regarding: `#include <stdlib.h>`  Nothing in this header file is being used by the posted code.   It is a poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not being used.  Suggest removing that statement.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s",&table1);`  1) This results in a warning from the compiler:  *untitled.c:14:17: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat=]*  2) when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  Note: the returned value is a count of the number of successful 'input format conversion specifiers'.  In the current scenario any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred. (cont)

Comment: (cont)  3) when using the format specifiers `%s` and/or `%[...]` always include a max characters modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer as those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoids any possible buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you pass your arrays they decay to *pointers* to their first element. For "array" arguments something like e.g. `char table1[]` is actually `char *table1`. And this is a problem when you try to use the address-of operator `&` in `scanf`.

When you use `&table1` in the `scanf` call you get a pointer *to the pointer*, which has the type `char **`, not the expected `char *`. This mismatch between the format `%s` and the expected type leads to *undefined behavior* and probably your crash.

The solution to this crash is to never use the address-of operator for reading strings (with e.g. the `%s` format), as it's even wrong when you have an actual array:

```
scanf("%s",table1);
```

---

As for the problem of making all elements of `Username` point to the single string in `table1`, I recommend that you use arrays of *arrays* for `Username` instead:

```
char Username[500][20];
```

This array decays to a pointer to an array, with the type of `char (*)[20]`, which needs to be part of the `Register` function declaration:

```
void Register(char (*Username)[20]);
```

Then you can use this directly in the call to `scanf`:

```
scanf("%19s", Username[i]);
```

Also note how I limited the length of the input string, so you can't read more than the arrays can handle (and it's 19 because the array need to fit the string null-terminator as well).

Comment: Thanks it worked just tried it thanks a lot :) , pointers are something that confuse me a lot need to work with them a bit more

Comment: Thanks a lot now the whole programm runs smoothly :)  also Is there a good website for people to reference that explains a lot of this stuff in more detail?

Comment: @NikosTypaldos _also Is there a good website for people to reference that explains a lot of this stuff in more detail?_   Yes, this one.  In the case of your question in particular, it has been asked many times, and answered properly almost as many times.

Answer (score 1):

In this statement

```
scanf("%s",&table1);
```

instead of reading a string into the array pointed to by the pointer table1 the string is read into the pointer itself.

You have to write

```
scanf("%s",table1);
```

Also the function `Register` does not make great sense because all elements of the array `Username` will point to the first character of the array table1. That is all elements of the array will point to the first character of the last string that was read.

You need to allocate memory dynamically. Also the second parameter of the function is redundant.

The function cam look the following way

```
size_t Register( char *Username[], size_t n )
{
    char record[20];
    int i = 0;

    for ( ; i < n && scanf( "%19s", record ) == 1; i++ )
    {
        Username[i] = malloc( strlen( record ) + 1 );
        strcpy( Username[i], record ); 
        printf( "for i = %zu username[%zu] is %s\n\n", i, i, Username[i] );
    }

    return i;
}
```

And in main the function can be called like

```
size_t n = Register( Username, 500 );
```

\Of course you will need to free all allocated memory.

Comment: So the function register does not read strings and stores them into pointers for example like this https://i1.wp.com/overiq.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/memory-representation-of-array-of-pointers-1504599930139.png

Comment: @NikosTypaldos You need to allocate an arrya for each pointer pf the array.